# Camera stream fails to open in ionic capacitor framework

Tags: ionic-framework, capacitor

I am trying to make a camera app using capacitor on an ionic framework. My code runs absolutely well on my web browser though when I build it on my phone it fails to open the camera stream and shows a blank icon as below.
[this is shown on my mobile when I click the camera button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/twJD1.jpg)

My code is as follows:

```
import { Plugins, CameraResultType, CameraSource } from '@capacitor/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['home.page.scss']
})
export class HomePage {
  photo: any;
  constructor() { }

  async takePicture() {
    const { Camera } = Plugins;
    const image = await Plugins.Camera.getPhoto({
      quality: 100,
      allowEditing: true,
      source: CameraSource.Camera,
      resultType: CameraResultType.Uri
    });

  this.photo = image.webPath;

  }
}
```

Please help, Thanks.